# In shiny / flexdashboards how can I change the values of columns through an input where multiple=TRUE?

Tags: r, shiny

I just can't seem to figure out how to change the value of columns in a dataframe within flexdashboard/shiny when `multiple = TRUE`. In the example below I can change x and y by selecting them individually. What I want to accomplish is when I have both x and y selected df$x becomes 3 and df$y becomes 2.

But when are both selected only the first one selected is changed.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
    runtime: shiny
---

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 1:10)

selectInput("var", label = "Change:", 
        choices =  list("no change", "x","y"), 
        multiple =TRUE,
        selected = "no change"
        )

renderDataTable({
  if(input$var == "no change")  {df <- df} 
  if(input$var %in% "x")  {df$x <- 3}  
  if(input$var %in% "y")  {df$y <- 2} 
  return(df)
   })
```
````

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For context, below is snapshot of the output from the code above, on which there is no app output:

*Image 0*

[image: Image 0]

---

You were almost there--just missing `else` before the last two `if`'s, and the corresponding line breaks (similarly, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43740818/7050882)).

````
---
title: "Please remember to make [reprex posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :)"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r now-including-else}

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 1:10)

selectInput("var", label = "Change:", 
            choices =  list("no change", "x","y"), 
            multiple =TRUE,
            selected = "no change"
            )

renderDataTable({
  if(input$var == "no change")  {
    df <- df
  }
  else if(input$var %in% "x")  {
    df$x <- 3
  }
  else if(input$var %in% "y")  {df$y <- 2} 
  return(df)
})
```
````

P.S. [Reprex posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

Some snapshots of the output from the code suggested:

*Image 1*

### [image: Image 1]

*Image 2*

### [image: Image 2]

*Image 3*

[image: Image 3]

Comment: I've added in the preamble but sadly your code doesn't appear to solve the issue when both x & y are selected at the same time.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit further?

Comment: What I want to accomplish is when I have both x and y selected df$x becomes 3 and df$y becomes 2.